# psremoting not working anymore

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I found the answer which looks a bit strange to me.
Although everything seems ok (fw ok, enter-pssession to localhost ok) i did the following.
1. on the workstation with PS 3.0 i did
      enable-psremoting -force  -->no better result.
2. Then i did on the same machine
      enable-psremoting    (without -force, and saying yes to all question)
       and everything works again.

Maybe someone has an explanation for this.

Comment: Have you tried running `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` on the client?

Comment: Are these domain-joined or workgroup PCs?

Comment: Does the Windows Firewall on the remote client (still) allow inbound connections to the service (port 5985/tcp)?